# Is there any publicly available information about how sqlmap works?

Tags: sqlmap

I want to understand the deep theory behind sqlmap - the decision making of the programm - how is it done? Is there any public paper? (There is still an option to read and understand sqlmap code and use -vvv switch).

I'm searching for a visualisation of sqlmap's decision tree.

Note: I know how SQL injection works and I'm familiar with sqlmap's wiki.

Comment: Yeah, i know how sql injection works and have read already the wiki. I'm interested how sqlmap decides which database is there and which version. It makes specific payloads to test the database and based on the response it decides which branch it should go further. I'm just curious how it works, but the codebase is really big and complex, so I search for academic paper or something in this direction (which i was unable to find) which would explain it more or less in detail

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to look at the [list of presentations](https://github.com/sqlmapproject/sqlmap/wiki/Presentations) maintained by the sqlmap project.  For example, they list *sqlmap - Under the Hood* and link to the [slides](http://www.slideshare.net/stamparm/ph-days-2013miroslavstamparsqlmapunderthehood).  The same talk as presented by the author is [no longer available on Youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PMBIoyyOlws) (unfortunate, since slide decks often leave out the meat of the discussion).  (Of course, there are many other presentations and tutorials on [Youtube](https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=sqlmap), but probably less on the deep internals).

Comment: youtube link is dead! :(

Comment: Thanks, @Slslam, I updated the answer a little but it appears that particular video has vanished off the Internet.  Sadly, it's niche content.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9Cman0EHkSU